# Calling and activity when booting of android is finished

Tags: android, mobile

I have an application developed in android. I want to call it when android finishes its booting, means when the phone starts.

How I can do this ?

Thanks,
Pravin

Comment: Do you have root rights on the system or does it has to be a solution nomatter what rights are available?

Comment: it has to be a solution nomatter what rights are available. PLease let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a BroadcastReceiver

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    public class YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
            {
             //do something like start an activity or service           }
            }
```

in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".YourReceiver ">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be annoying for users. Like when Windows XP lets 3rd party programs after boot and the user has to close those goddamn application everytime.

Anyway.... 
create an intent receiver with

```
 <action android:value="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Read this [tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/launch_activity_on_system-emulator_startup-t428.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a BroadcastReceiver and register that in your menifest.xml file. Have a look at the following code

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    try {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Device restarted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Add the following in your menifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

remember to add the following permission as well

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
```